# SetContent in TinyMce from api call in Angular 4

Tags: angular, tinymce

**I am trying to Implement tinymce in my angular 4 project.**
**I would like to get the content from the web api and display in the tinymce editor**

**This is my component**

```js
import {Component,OnInit,OnDestroy,AfterViewInit,EventEmitter,Input,Output,
  Inject,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
  
declare var tinymce: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'first-angular-project-tiny-mce',
  template: `<textarea id="{{elementId}}"></textarea>`,
  styleUrls: ['./tiny-mce.component.css'],
})

export class TinyMceComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() elementId: any;
  @Output() onEditorKeyup = new EventEmitter<any>();
  editor;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
      skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
      automatic_uploads: true,
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        
        //i am trying to set content here
        this.editor.setContent('<span>test</span>');

        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
    );
       },
    });
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }

}
```

**This is my component markup**

```html
   <first-angular-project-tiny-mce [elementId]="Editor"  (onEditorKeyup)="keyupHandler($event)"></first-angular-project-tiny-mce>
```

**When i am setting the content i am getting the following error**
[image]

**can any one let me know what is the right way to set the content in tinymce?**

Comment: It looks like there is a parse function used in getContent() which is not null checking

Comment: how can i set the content?

Comment: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3413 It looks like you can wrap the setContent call in a setTimeout function to get it to work.  `setTimeout(()=>{ editor.setContent()},10)`